# Custom Keyboard Load But Doesn't work When Typing In Android Device

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to use my custom keyboard in android application. When I click Edit Text my keyboard popup and show properly, but when I press keyboards button doesn't type anything and I don't know why?

Here is my CustomKeyboard class:

```
/**
 * Created by KHALED on 8/10/2015.
 */


import android.app.Activity;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;




class CustomKeyboard {

    /** A link to the KeyboardView that is used to render this CustomKeyboard. */
    private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    /** A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}. */
    private Activity mHostActivity;
    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    private boolean caps = false;
    /** The key (code) handler. */

    private KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener() {


        public final static int CodeDelete   = -5; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
        public final static int CodeCancel   = -3; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL
        public final static int CodePrev     = 55000;
        public final static int CodeAllLeft  = 55001;
        public final static int CodeLeft     = 55002;
        public final static int CodeRight    = 55003;
        public final static int CodeAllRight = 55004;
        public final static int CodeNext     = 55005;
        public final static int CodeClear    = 55006;
        public final static int KEYCODE_SHIFT    = -1;
        public final static int KEYCODE_DONE   = -4;

        @Override public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in primaryCode
            // Get the EditText and its Editable
            View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
            if( focusCurrent==null || focusCurrent.getClass()!=EditText.class ) return;
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();

            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if( primaryCode==CodeCancel ) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeDelete ) {
                if( editable!=null && start>0 ) editable.delete(start - 1, start);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeClear ) {
                if( editable!=null ) editable.clear();
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeLeft ) {
                if( start>0 ) edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeRight ) {
                if (start < edittext.length()) edittext.setSelection(start + 1);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllLeft ) {
                edittext.setSelection(0);
            } else if( primaryCode==CodeAllRight ) {
                edittext.setSelection(edittext.length());
            }else if( primaryCode==KEYCODE_DONE ) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
            // else if( primaryCode==KEYCODE_SHIFT ) {
            //   caps = !caps;
            // keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            //kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            //    }
            else { // insert character
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
            }
        }


        @Override public void onPress(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
        }

        @Override public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        }

        @Override public void swipeDown() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeLeft() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeRight() {
        }

        @Override public void swipeUp() {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Create a custom keyboard, that uses the KeyboardView (with resource id <var>viewid</var>) of the <var>host</var> activity,
     * and load the keyboard layout from xml file <var>layoutid</var> (see {@link Keyboard} for description).
     * Note that the <var>host</var> activity must have a <var>KeyboardView</var> in its layout (typically aligned with the bottom of the activity).
     * Note that the keyboard layout xml file may include key codes for navigation; see the constants in this class for their values.
     * Note that to enable EditText's to use this custom keyboard, call the {@link #registerEditText(int)}.
     *
     * @param host The hosting activity.
     * @param viewid The id of the KeyboardView.
     * @param layoutid The id of the xml file containing the keyboard layout.
     */
    public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
        mHostActivity= host;
        mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview balloons
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        // Hide the standard keyboard initially
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    /** Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible. */
    public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
        return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v. */
    public void showCustomKeyboard( View v ) {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
        if( v!=null ) ((InputMethodManager)mHostActivity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard invisible. */
    public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
     *
     * @param resid The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom keyboard.
     */
    public void registerEditText(int resid) {
        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        EditText edittext= (EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the edit box loses focus
            @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if( hasFocus ) showCustomKeyboard(v); else hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
        });
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus (but that had the keyboard hidden).
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });
        // Disable standard keyboard hard way
        // NOTE There is also an easy way: 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
        edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
                int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
                edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
                edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
                return true; // Consume touch event
            }
        });
        // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
        edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

}


// NOTE How can we change the background color of some keys (like the shift/ctrl/alt)?
// NOTE What does android:keyEdgeFlags do/mean
```

And this is keyboard design(kurdkbr.xml):

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="50dp"

    >
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1633" android:keyLabel="١" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1634" android:keyLabel="٢"/>
        <Key android:codes="1635" android:keyLabel="٣"/>
        <Key android:codes="1636" android:keyLabel="٤"/>
        <Key android:codes="1637" android:keyLabel="٥"/>
        <Key android:codes="1638" android:keyLabel="٦"/>
        <Key android:codes="1639" android:keyLabel="٧"/>
        <Key android:codes="1640" android:keyLabel="٨"/>
        <Key android:codes="1641" android:keyLabel="٩"/>
        <Key android:codes="1632" android:keyLabel="٠" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1602" android:keyLabel="ق" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1700" android:keyLabel="ڤ"/>
        <Key android:codes="1601" android:keyLabel="ف"/>
        <Key android:codes="1594" android:keyLabel="غ"/>
        <Key android:codes="1593" android:keyLabel="ع"/>
        <Key android:codes="1607" android:keyLabel="ه"/>
        <Key android:codes="1607" android:keyLabel="ه‌"/>
        <Key android:codes="1578" android:keyLabel="ت" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="تط"/>
        <Key android:codes="1581" android:keyLabel="ح"/>
        <Key android:codes="1582" android:keyLabel="خ" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1588" android:keyLabel="ش" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1587" android:keyLabel="س"/>
        <Key android:codes="1610" android:keyLabel="ی"/>
        <Key android:codes="1576" android:keyLabel="ب"/>
        <Key android:codes="1604" android:keyLabel="ل"/>
        <Key android:codes="1717" android:keyLabel="ڵ"/>
        <Key android:codes="1575" android:keyLabel="ا"/>
        <Key android:codes="1606" android:keyLabel="ن"/>
        <Key android:codes="1580" android:keyLabel="ج"/>
        <Key android:codes="1670" android:keyLabel="چ" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1586" android:keyLabel="ز" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1585" android:keyLabel="ر"/>
        <Key android:codes="1685" android:keyLabel="ڕ"/>
        <Key android:codes="1583" android:keyLabel="د"/>
        <Key android:codes="1608" android:keyLabel="و"/>
        <Key android:codes="1734" android:keyLabel="ۆ"/>
        <Key android:codes="1603" android:keyLabel="ك"/>
        <Key android:codes="1711" android:keyLabel="گ"/>
        <Key android:codes="1574" android:keyLabel="ئ"/>
        <Key android:codes="63,33,58,44" android:keyLabel="\? ! : " android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

And keyboard view layout:

```
  <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/blue_steel"
        android:keyTextSize="20dp"
        android:iconPreview="@drawable/samplekeybackground"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

And finally in main class:

```
 public class NewPost extends ActionBarActivity {
 CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_post);



        mCustomKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.kurdkbr );
        Keyboard mKeyboard= new Keyboard(NewPost.this,R.xml.kurdkbr);
        mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.title_neew_post);
       // mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.content_new_post);
        KeyboardView mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)findViewById(R.id.keyboardview);
        // Attach the keyboard to the view
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
        // Do not show the preview balloons
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        }
 }
```

Can anybody tell me what I forgot to handle?
As I say keyboard show properly but don't type?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting same error. Instead of extending ActionBarActivity ,try to extend Activity. Your above code works in lollipop devices but not below.